# Como crear un boton de enlace para un chatbot de whastapp con puro javascript

Tags: javascript, web, programación-móvil, whatsapp

necesito ayuda para crear 3 botones los cuales debo mostrar en un chat Bot de WhatsApp, cada botón debe redirigir al usuario a un sitio diferente pero la herramienta para este Bot solo permite utilizar código JavaScript y no conozco mucho ese lenguaje, no se como hacer los botones y que cuando el usuario de click en cualquiera de los 3 botones sea redirigido a la web o app :(

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra lo que has intentado hasta el momento: lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Recuerda que [es.so] ni es un repositorio de código, ni un sitio de tutoriales.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: y que ha hecho o investigdo???